# Перестали открываться настройки системы в linux mint 18

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Не могу точно сказать после каких опреаций, тк редко пользовался данным функционалом, но перестали открываться настройки системы, параметры звука и добавление аплетов на панель. Возможно что то еще но я пока не заметил.

Графическая оболочка cinnamon.

Подскажите как такое возможно исправить.

Comment: А если создать нового пользователя - там всё ок?

Comment: @donRumata да, только что создал еще одного пользователя и у него такой проблемы нет

Comment: Попробуй сделать `mv ~/.config ~/.config_backup` и перезайди. Все настройки программуль, которые лежат в `~/.config` пересоздадутся заново при первом запуске. И если что - можно будет просто обратно драг энд дропнуть

Comment: @donRumata ваш совет помог, только необходимо было еще удалить директорию с конфигом после перемещения. Если вам не сложно - оформите ваш комментарий как ответ и я приму его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отладки обычно работает такая схема:

1. Создать нового пользователя. Если там то же самое - значит проблема в системе и надо копать с сторону `/etc`.
2. Если помогло - значит проблема чисто в профиле. Нормальные программы хранят свои настройки в `~/.config/<имя проги>`. Соответственно перемещаем папку с прогой в другое место или просто переименовываем. Проще всего сделать это со всей папкой конфигов: `mv ~/.config ~/.config_backup` и перезайти.